Help with Identifying a Japanese Font
Been looking everywhere for this font. Can anyone find a match? Thanks!


I know a little Japanese, so I know my way around the Japanese Internet quite well, and this seems to be the same font. At least he looks similar. This font is " 筑紫ゴシック Pro H " To search I used this site https://mojicity.jp/photokara/

It's close but not quite there. I'm placing close attention to the 、and the バ as the little dashes are lower and straighter than I've seen with most fonts. We're definitely in the right ballpark...

Did more investigating and the font is A-OTF Gothic MB101 Pr5 U. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction!
